# How exactly to track my life and not die

Tags: overwatch

I'm doing my best to never die but I'm not sure I'm doing it the proper way. My current K/D Ratio for Season 4 is 2.47. The way I track my life is this:

1. I know about how much damage every hero does.
2. When I see the red indicator that someone is firing me I'm trying to keep shooting but keep looking the health bar if it is going down.
3. If a healer is healing me I dont look much my health unless I'm under heavy damage.

I'm curious although how the pro player track their health. I'm seeing some pro matches with heroes like winston that leaves with 50hp. How exactly are they doing it? They estimate from the red indicator how much damage have taken? They look like me often their health? It seems like a bad way for me to take your eyes entirely off from the match to check in the down left corner for the health bar, We should always be looking around the center of the screen.

From my understanding you should keep track in the following things to keep alive:

- Hear ultimates from the opponents.
- Keep tracking of your abilities cooldown (for this im trying to get used of the effect indicator when the ability countdown gets to 0 in order to avoid looking directly to the ability).
- Keep tracking if someone is healing you.
- Keep tracking if someone is firing you and from which angle is firing you.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is an entirely opinionated question with no real answer. Pros practice a lot and just becomes habitual to look at and know their health.

Comment: How do you know that? maybe all the pro has a specific way to track it, if not then i would like to know that, in either case the answer might be specific

Comment: *"It seems like a bad way for me to take your eyes entirely off from the match to check in the down left corner for the health bar"* before alot of shooters used infinite regen where the screen goes red but returns to normal (like that in CoD or Gear of War) you had to look at a health bar/number and know when to pull out and use a medkit (like in the original CoD) or fall back to where there was a health kit (Half-Life, Doom, Wolfenstien 3D)

Comment: Checking your health should take about a millisecond.

Comment: Remember that the point of Overwatch is to win matches, not get a high K/D ratio.  One of the "tricks" in this video of [7 tricks grandmasters use](https://youtu.be/ok8uaelv9XY?t=145) involves intentionally dying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still searching for this answer:
We can see a top pro gamer how he track his life, how often etc in this video, he is using eye tracking technology

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to miss if you're not aware, but every hero has an audio indicator when they drop to low health (typically a gasping intake of breath and a heartbeat, but it can vary). The audio is different for each hero so you'll need to train yourself to listen out for different things while playing different characters.

If you plug "overwatch critical health sounds" into your favourite search engine, you should get a good bit more information on them.

Comment: if memory serves, the trigger amount is 75 health, so the sound goes off when damage takes you below that point

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing so much on the crosshair, your eyes should be wondering around, checking skill cooldowns, your team's ult status(by pressing tab), and of course checking HP.

When a pro Winston like Miro leaves with just 50 HP, he isn't just guessing that he has low HP. He is looking at his health bar constantly and checking them. It helps that Winston doesn't require precise aiming, so your eyes can wonder around a bit.